# Listing out the games installed in Windows 10 machine using c#

Tags: c#, uwp

I have tried package manager classes to get the list of installed packages in windows 10 machine.

```
PackageTypes type = PackageTypes.Main;                                           
IEnumerable<Package> packages = (IEnumerable<Package>) packageManager.FindPackagesWithPackageTypes(type); 
foreach(var package in packages){
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", package.Id.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("FullName: {0}", package.Id.FullName);
    Console.WriteLine("Version: {0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", package.Id.Version.Major, package.Id.Version.Minor,
        package.Id.Version.Build, package.Id.Version.Revision);
}
```

When I used the above code, getting all packages including games installed in windows 10 machine ,

but how can I separate only games from the list?
[image]
When I searched in ms store I found that In mss tore app there is filter in which I can able to select the games option which will show all games installed in the machine from ms store, any idea how they are filtering these games?

Comment: try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39435219/11362349)

Comment: I need not only steam apps, the games installed using windows app store, any idea?

Comment: How do you make the distinction between what is a game and not?

Comment: I think you can't distinct game from other apps. If you know what apps should be installed on end user's PC you can create 'white list'. Get all packages and yeild all that doesn't match your list.

Comment: Can any one has any idea how to get the installed games list in windows 10 machine using any other language like C++?

Comment: See [Is the Windows 10 Game Bar extensible?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/150601/10408).

Comment: There is no way to do this. The categorisations in the MS store are entirely within the store, they are not exposed to end-users in any sort of API.